# Convert filtered drawable to bitmap

Tags: java, android, drawable

I've got a drawable I'm applying a filter to using 
    drawable.setColorFilter (color, PorterDuff.MILTIPLY)

Then I'm taking the bitmap I used to create the drawable and putting it into a canvas so I can write text in the middle of the png. And finishing by writing

```
drawable.draw(canvas)
```

I want the text I add to always be white no matter what color filter is used but right now the text becomes whatever color is used for filtering.  I was thinking if I could convert the filtered drawable to a bitmap then add the text the it'd work but so far it hasnt. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
    public void setDrawableFilter(String text, int color) {

        mBitmap = scaleBitmap(250, 238);
        mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mBitmap);
        mDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

       addTextToBitmap(text);
}

public void addTextToBitmap(String text){
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(35);

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

    float xPercent = 0.38f;
    float yPercent = 0.58f;
    int textX = (int) (canvasWidth * xPercent);//
    int textY = (int) (canvasHeight * yPercent);

    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(text, canvasWidth / 2, textY, paint);
}
```

Comment: just call drawable.draw(canvas) followed by canvas.drawText(...)

Comment: The color filter is still applied to the text when I do this

Comment: color filter is associated with the Paint object,  just use the different Paint object

Comment: I tried adding a new paint and the color filter is still applied

Comment: see that: http://pastebin.com/JyuYWuAq