# Imageview drawable loses color filter after converting into bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-bitmap

I am applying a color filter to an imageview and trying to get the bitmap from that imageview.

```
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0x000000, myColor);
image_view.setColorFilter(filter);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image_view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

but the bitmap is not keeping the color filter I applied to it and I am getting the original image bitmap only.

below are the duplicate posts asked but it was not helpful:

[Drawable loses color filter after converting into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287510/drawable-loses-color-filter-after-converting-into-bitmap)

[Convert filtered drawable to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614835/convert-filtered-drawable-to-bitmap)

Comment: you likely need to draw your view on a new bitmap (*get a screenshot of the view*)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally!

We need to do following thing to get the bitmap with color filter applied on it.

```
image_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_view.getDrawingCache());
```

Hope this will help someone struggling like me.